# Capybara: unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I was testing a confirm dialog in my app.
Getting the following error when I was running acceptance test using cucumber and capybara:

> unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)(Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)

Using latest ruby (2.2.2) and chrome (46.0.2490.80). Found some answers about updating the selenium, but my selenium-webdriver gem is updated (2.48.1). Also didn't work for firefox (42.0).

Comment: Why are you providing a chrome version if the error is mentioning Firefox?

Comment: Since Firefox 42 just released you'll probably need to wait for the next selenium-webdriver release for compatibility - revert to Firefox 41 - for chrome you should update chromedriver

Comment: No, the latest version of Firefox works with the latest version of Selenium. Are you trying to run this headless? Make sure your xvfb is setup correctly.